# Hex editing to change a name?

Tags: windows, hex, editing, names

I wrote a program a while back, but have since then lost the source code. When I open the program up in a hex editor, I cannot find the name anywhere in the code (so that I can change it). The name that I am referring to is the one at the top of the window. Is there any alternative way I could do this?

Comment: Which hex editor did you use, and if you used the find function, does it consider the possibility that the string might be a Unicode UTF-16 string? It might appear on the right side of the hex dump as something like: -.N.o.t.e.p.a.d.

Comment: Ah, that was it! I changed it to unicode and it worked flawlessly. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the name is in Unicode, which means there will be an extra `\0` character in between each character of the name. Search for that using wildcards to skip the null bytes.